# pygame quit button not functioning properly

Tags: python, pygame

my quit button is working in my pygame but only partly. it works once i have just run the game, but after i have been killed in game and the game_loop is reset, the quit button just resets the game loop when i press it and doesn't close the window. it's like it has changed it's function to the same as the function of when the player get's killed if that makes sense.

i am just going to show you my whole games code to make it easier. (btw my game is being changed currently so some things might be in the wrong place and stuff just don't worry about it).

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
dis_width = 500
dis_height = 500
game_exit = False
hit = False
FPS = 150
record = 0
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('RACRZ')


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#COLOURS
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0 ,0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
sky_blue = (0, 136, 239)
#VEHICLE
bg = pygame.image.load('c:\\users\\riley\\pictures\\Saved Pictures\\spaceImg_bg.png')
carImg = pygame.image.load('c:\\users\\riley\\pictures\\Saved Pictures\\space invader1.png')
car_width = 32
car_height = 33


vel = 3
#projectile
enemyImg = pygame.image.load('c:\\users\\riley\\pictures\\saved pictures\\projectile1.png')
explosionImg = pygame.image.load('c:\\users\\riley\\pictures\\saved pictures\\explosion 1.png')


def car(x, y):
    game_display.blit(carImg, (x, y))

def enemy(enemyx, enemyy):
    game_display.blit(enemyImg, (enemyx, enemyy))
def enemy2(enemyx, enemyy):
    game_display.blit(enemyImg, (enemyx, enemyy))
def enemy3(enemyx, enemyy):
    game_display.blit(enemyImg, (enemyx, enemyy))
def enemy4(enemyx, enemyy):
    game_display.blit(enemyImg, (enemyx, enemyy))
def enemy5(enemyx, enemyy):
    game_display.blit(enemyImg, (enemyx, enemyy))
def enemy6(enemyx, enemyy):
    game_display.blit(enemyImg, (enemyx, enemyy))

def explode(x, y):
    game_display.blit(explosionImg, (x, y))
#TEXT
def textobjects(text, font):
    textsurface = font.render(text, True, green)
    return textsurface, textsurface.get_rect()

#RESTART MESSAGE
def message_display(text, colour, locationX, locationY):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
    text = largeText.render('HIT', True, (colour))
    game_display.blit(text, (locationX, locationY))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()

def collision(ex, ey, ew, eh, x, y, w, h):
    if x > ex and x < ex + ew or x + w > ex and x + w < ex + ew:
        if y > ey and y < ey + eh or y + h > ey and y + h < ey + eh:
            print ('HIT')
            hit = True
            game_loop()





def score(rounds):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)
    text = font.render(f'ROUND {rounds}', True, green)
    game_display.blit(text, (0,0))

#GAME LOOP
def game_loop():
#beggining car location
    x = dis_width * 0.45
    y = dis_height * 0.8
#movement variables
    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    loop_count = 0

    enemy_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
    enemy_starty = -1000


    enemy2_startx = -1000
    enemy2_starty = random.uniform(0, dis_height)

    enemy3_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
    enemy3_starty = -24

    enemy4_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
    enemy4_starty = 500
    #goes from top side diagonaly to bottom left
    enemy5_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
    enemy5_starty = -24
    #goes from bottom side diagonaly to top right
    enemy6_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
    enemy6_starty = 500

    enemy_speed = 3
    enemy_width = 24
    enemy_height = 24




#game has not been quit
    game_exit = False
#while the game is running this will happen
    while not game_exit:
        #quit button
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #assingning keys to movement    
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change -= vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change += vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change += vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change -= vel
                elif event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    print ('escape')
                    game_exit = True
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 game_exit = True



            #stops vehicle from moving after key press
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0
        #moves vehicle
        y += y_change 
        x += x_change
        #display colour
        game_display.blit(bg, (0,0))
        #spawns objects       
        if loop_count >= 10:
            enemy3_startx += enemy_speed
            enemy3_starty += enemy_speed
            enemy3(enemy3_startx, enemy3_starty)    

        if loop_count >= 15:
            enemy4_startx -= enemy_speed 
            enemy4_starty -= enemy_speed
            enemy4(enemy4_startx, enemy4_starty)

        if loop_count >= 20:
            enemy5_startx -= enemy_speed
            enemy5_starty += enemy_speed
            enemy5(enemy5_startx, enemy5_starty)

        if loop_count >= 25:
            enemy6_startx += enemy_speed
            enemy6_starty -= enemy_speed
            enemy6(enemy6_startx, enemy6_starty)

        car(x,y)
        enemy(enemy_startx, enemy_starty)
        enemy2(enemy2_startx, enemy2_starty)

        score(loop_count)

        enemy2_startx += enemy_speed
        enemy_starty += enemy_speed
        if hit == True:
            game_loop = 0
#MAKES DISPLAY BOUNDARIES
#car boundaries
        if x > dis_width - car_width:
            x = 0 
        elif x < 0:
            x = dis_width - car_width
        elif y > dis_height - car_height:
            y = 0
        elif y < 0:
            y = dis_height - car_height
#boundaries for enemy1
        if enemy_starty > dis_height:
            enemy_starty = 0 - enemy_height
            enemy_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width - enemy_width)
            #loop_count will count the number of times enemy1 passes through the screen
            loop_count = loop_count + 1
            print(loop_count)
        # ex, ey, ew, eh, x, y, w, h
        collision(enemy_startx, enemy_starty, enemy_width, enemy_height, x, y, car_width, car_height)
        collision(enemy2_startx, enemy2_starty, enemy_width, enemy_height, x, y, car_width, car_height)
        collision(enemy3_startx, enemy3_starty, enemy_width, enemy_height, x, y, car_width, car_height)
        collision(enemy4_startx, enemy4_starty, enemy_width, enemy_height, x, y, car_width, car_height)
        collision(enemy5_startx, enemy5_starty, enemy_width, enemy_height, x, y, car_width, car_height)
        collision(enemy6_startx, enemy6_starty, enemy_width, enemy_height, x, y, car_width, car_height)
#boundaries for enemy2
        if enemy2_startx > dis_width:
            enemy2_startx = 0 - enemy_width
            enemy2_starty = random.uniform(0, dis_height - enemy_height)
#enemy3 boundaries
        if enemy3_startx > dis_width:
            enemy3_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
            enemy3_starty = -24        
#enemy4 boundaries
        if enemy4_startx < 0 - enemy_width:
            enemy4_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
            enemy4_starty = 500
#enemy5 boundaries
        if enemy5_startx < 0 - enemy_width:
            enemy5_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
            enemy5_starty = -24
#enemy6 boundaries
        if enemy6_startx > dis_width:
            enemy6_startx = random.uniform(0, dis_width)
            enemy6_starty = 500
        #record checker/ set
        global record
        roundnum = loop_count
        if roundnum > record:
            record = roundnum


        #updates screen after movements
        pygame.display.update()
        #FPS
        clock.tick(FPS)
#loops through code
if game_exit == True:
    pygame.quit()
game_loop()
print (f'your record is {record}')
```

it would mean allot you could find the error in my code. 
if you find any other issues please let me know thanks.

Comment: There's a spot in the `game_loop()` function that does `if hit == True:`,  `game_loop = 0` which destroys the function by the same name at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit of code here is quite wrong. Try this in a `while True:` loop:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
            pygame.display.update()
```

[`The pygame.display.update` bit is in a different place so delete it where it was and copy and past this in isntead.]

Comment: Delete that bit and just keep this code then it should work after that.